# Regularity period or length of periodic orbits around center

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f$ be a vectorial field. Suppose that de differential equation $\dot{x}=f(x)$ has a center around some point.
What kind of regularity (under some suitable regularity hypothesis on $f$) can we expect from the function $T(x)$ which returns the period of the orbit of the point $x$ or from the function  $L(x)$ which returns the length of the orbit of the point $x$?

It is clear that from the regularity of one of them one can prove the regularity of the other one.

My idea was to somehow prove that the period of the orbits contained in a compact subset must be bounded. Then using continuity of solutions with respect to initial conditions and the Flow Box theorem I could prove that the periodic solutions contained in the neighborhood of another must "close" at the same time.

Could anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Judging by your use of the term *center*, you mean a **two-dimensional** vector field, of course? If not, I think there is no hope for such a result.

Comment: @user539887 Yes, I do

Comment: It appears that if the compact set in question does not contain equilibria then a proof is rather simple.  When there is an equilibrium, I can imagine that the idea of "blowing up singularities", as used in the theory of (Andronov-)Hopf bifurcation, could be perhaps of use here?

Comment: @user539887 could you give an idea of the proof for the first case?

Comment: Take a periodic point $x$ of prime period $T$, and a flow-box around it. By the continuity of the flow, nearby points hit, after a time close to $T$, the flow-box. Let $y$ be a periodic point sufficiently close to $x$. Now, by using the Jordan curve theorem we prove that it not only hits the flow-box, but it hits itself (a picture is worth a thousand words; unfortunately, I'm not good at drawing pictures). If we believe that, the continuous (even $C^1$, I think) dependence seems to be a consequence of the regularity of the flow-box mapping.